# Shift arrow icon in sap.m.Panel control of ui5

Tags: sapui5, panel

Can we shift arrow icon to right in `sap.m.Panel` in SAPUI5, I tried to search it through its documentation but unable to find it. Please suggest if it is possible to do SO by some customization of control.

Answer (score 1):

Not the preferred way upto my knowledge and I don't know any other way to do it.

```
.sapMPanelWrappingDiv .sapUiIconPointer{
   right : 0;
}
```

> Use right : 0!important; if not working with above code.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: I don't think this is a good decision UX-wise...

Anyways you have several choices to achieve this from trivial to complex:

- Use CSS to position icon to the right as mentioned by santhosh
- Hide the expand icon via CSS (`display: none;`) and use the headerToolbar aggregation. In there you can do what you want and place a button to the right with a press-listerner expanding/collapsing the panel
- Override `sap.m.PanelRenderer.renderHeader` and adjust the icon placement right in the renderer

Here is my CSS solution (which I would go for):

```
.sapMPanel.myPanelIconRight .sapMPanelExpandableIcon {
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
}
.sapMPanel.myPanelIconRight .sapMPanelWrappingDiv .sapMPanelHdr, 
.sapMPanel.myPanelIconRight .sapMPanelWrappingDivTb .sapMIBar.sapMTB {
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-right: 3rem;
}
```

Please note the class I `myPanelIconRight` attached to the `sap.m.Panel` control to separate our custom styling from the UI5 CSS.

BR
Chris